# Writing to a binary file python

Tags: python, numpy, binary

I want to write something to a binary file using python.

I am simply doing:

```
import numpy as np

f = open('binary.file','wb')
i=4
j=5.55
f.write('i'+'j') #where do i specify that i is an integer and j is a double?

g = open('binary.file','rb')
first = np.fromfile(g,dtype=np.uint32,count = 1)
second = np.fromfile(g,dtype=np.float64,count = 1)

print first, second
```

The output is just:
[] []

I know it is very easy to do this in Matlab "fwrite(binary.file, i, 'int32');", but I want to do it in python.

Comment: You do not write 4 and 5.55 into the file. You write 105 (the ASCII code of `'i'`) and 106 (the ASCII code of `'j'`).

Comment: The line `f.write('i'+'j')` is writing the string `'ij'` to a file. You will want to use [struct.pack](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html#struct.pack) in order to properly encode your data as binary.

Comment: Since you are using `numpy.fromfile` to load the data, the most natural thing to do is use `numpy.ndarray.tofile` to store the data. (But note that the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) recommend using `numpy.save` and `numpy.load` instead.)

Comment: nump.save saves the data to a .npy file..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be having some confusion about types in Python.

The expression `'i' + 'j'` is adding two strings together. This results in the string `ij`, which is most likely written to the file as two bytes.

The variable `i` is already an `int`. You can write it to a file as a 4-byte integer in a couple of different ways (which also apply to the float `j`):

1. Use the `struct` module as detailed in [how to write integer number in particular no of bytes in python ( file writing)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2294608/2988730). Something like this:

   ```
   import struct
   with open('binary.file', 'wb') as f:
       f.write(struct.pack("i", i))
   ```

   You would use the `'d'` specifier to write `j`.
2. Use the numpy module to do the writing for you, which is especially convenient since you are already using it to read the file. The method [`ndarray.tofile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html#numpy.ndarray.tofile) is made just for this purpose:

   ```
   i = 4
   j = 5.55
   with open('binary.file', 'wb') as f:
       np.array(i, dtype=np.uint32).tofile(f)
       np.array(j, dtype=np.float64).tofile(f)
   ```

Note that in both cases I use `open` as a context manager when writing the file with a `with` block. This ensures that the file is closed, even if an error occurs during writing.

Answer (score -1):

That's because you are trying to write a string(edited) into a binary file.  You also don't close the file before trying to read it again.
If you want to write ints or strings to a binary file try adding the below code:

```
import numpy as np
import struct

f = open('binary.file','wb')
i = 4
if isinstance(i, int):
    f.write(struct.pack('i', i)) # write an int
elif isinstance(i, str):
    f.write(i) # write a string
else:
    raise TypeError('Can only write str or int')

f.close()

g = open('binary.file','rb')
first = np.fromfile(g,dtype=np.uint32,count = 1)
second = np.fromfile(g,dtype=np.float64,count = 1)

print first, second
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out the floating number.

print first, second
[4] []

The more pythonic file handler way:

```
import numpy as np
import struct

with open ('binary.file','wb') as f:
    i = 4
    if isinstance(i, int):
        f.write(struct.pack('i', i)) # write an int
    elif isinstance(i, str):
        f.write(i) # write a string
    else:
        raise TypeError('Can only write str or int')

with open('binary.file','rb') as g:
    first = np.fromfile(g,dtype=np.uint32,count = 1)
    second = np.fromfile(g,dtype=np.float64,count = 1)

print first, second
```

Comment: Might it be better to use the `with open('binary.file', 'wb') as f:` syntax in this example to establish better practices?

Comment: Sure, it solves the closing file issue.  I was trying to keep it as close to the original code as possible. Edit: added with open...

Comment: I would either use Numpy's `tofile` and `fromfile` in pairs, or the `struct` module for both reading and writing. Also, he wasn't writing a sum to the file, but `'ij'` as a string.

Also, I am not sure this isn't a duplicate of e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129257/python-writing-int-to-a-binary-file.

Comment: You are right David, I missed he had '' around the vars.

Comment: What about `j`?

Comment: I literally said: I'll leave it to you to figure out the floating number.   Can't have other people do all the work for you, or you'll never learn :D

Comment: Check this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807863/how-to-output-list-of-floats-to-a-binary-file-in-python